# How to pull values from a table, calculate them and display the result on a page

Tags: php, mysql, risk-analysis

[image]

Hi, I'm doing a coding about risk analysis based on the image above (a table). Unfortunately I don't know how to translate the formula into a coding and display the result on a php page. Basically the formula involves multiplying of likelyhood * severity for each row, add between each of them and then average it (divide by 3). In short

```
result1 = (likelyhood1 * severity1)
result2 = (likelyhood2 * severity2)
result3 = (likelyhood3 * severity3)

a = (result1 + result2 + result3) / 3
```

Result "a" is then displayed to the same php page (I'm using mysql database).

I did try looking up for answers but to no avail. Here's where I'm stuck.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","risk");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

//$res1 = 

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Not that hard of a thing to do. Just loop over the rows do the multiplication, add it to a running total then divide.

Comment: It's about getting rows from db. That's all. Use `mysql_fetch_array()`; in loop

Answer (score 3):

You can query that directly:

```
SELECT SUM(likelyhood * severity) / COUNT(*) FROM Persons
```

EDIT:

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT AVG(likelyhood * severity) FROM Persons
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$total = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $total += $row['likelyhood'] * $row['severity'];
}
$a = $total/3;
```

Comment: use Klaus Byskov Pedersen's answer. its much simpler to do it in the query and the second query he shows will help if you need to a variable amount of rows instead of just a set number.